# Issues with the wording "The treasure (?) must stand forth to himself the approved owner"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositional-verbs

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, [Chapter XXIII, passage 378/379](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_23), published 1892)

> That was indeed the chief singularity, the one thing conspicuous in their island life; the presence of that chest of bills and specie dominated the mind like a cathedral; and there were besides connected with it, certain irking problems well fitted to occupy the idle. Two thousand pounds were due to the Sydney firm: two thousand pounds were clear profit, and fell to be divided in varying proportions among six. It had been agreed how the partners were to range; every pound of capital subscribed, every pound that fell due in wages, was to count for one “lay.” . . . eight hundred and forty “lays” in all. . .
> . . .
>
> From talking and brooding on these figures, it was but a step to opening the chest; and once the chest open, the glamour of the cash was irresistible. Each felt that he must see his **treasure** separate with the eye of flesh, handle it in the hard coin, mark it for his own, and **stand forth to himself the approved owner**. And here an insurmountable difficulty barred the way. . .

I've an issue with this wording. First, I am not sure what the subject of "stand forth to himself the approved owner" is. I suppose it's "treasure" - "the *treasure* must stand forth to himself the approved owner" - and I consider "the approved owner" an *apposition* to "himself".
Regarding the meaning, I take "the treasure must stand forth to himself" to mean 'the treasure must loom up or hulk up in front of himself - the approved owner'.

Comment: I cannot answer this question, but the first problem you're having is that you've parsed the sentence incorrectly. By distributing "he must", we get "he must see his treasure [...], he must handle it [...], he must mark it [...], and he must stand forth to himself the approved owner."

Comment: Expanding it further, the sentence could be "[...] [he must] stand forth to himself the approved owner [of the treasure]." I would also guess it could be expanded to "[...] [he must] stand forth to himself [as] the approved owner [of the treasure]," just based on the structure, but now we run into the problem that I have no idea what it means to "stand forth to [oneself]". You may need to consult a dictionary from that time for "stand forth".

Comment: My guess is ***stand forth to*** here is Stevenson's unusual / obsolete alternative to ***defend***. Each felt compelled to take hold of his treasure, and defend his right of ownership / defend himself as the rightful owner thereof.

Comment: Why do you downvote this question?

Comment: It's not relevant to *learning English*, as is the case with so many unusual / obsolete usages you keep turning up in this book.

Comment: Have you read ELL-Meta https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/is-historical-english-interpretation-part-of-ells-remit?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to know that we say  "Why are you downvoting this question?" compare: He downvotes questions every day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading it wrong. It's an elision of "he must" ("he must stand forth…"), like in every item of the list:

> Each felt that he must
>
> - see his treasure separate with the eye of flesh,
> - handle it in the hard coin,
> - mark it for his own, and
> - stand forth to himself the approved owner

It's not possible to read "treasure" as the subject here because "separate" is an adjective and not the start of a list of verbs associated with "treasure". Treasure is also the "it" used twice in the sentence—we don't really use "him" for inanimate objects.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct parse. Meaning: must see himself as the approved owner.

Answer (score 1):

> **Each** felt that **he** must see his treasure separate with the eye of flesh, handle **it** in the hard coin, mark **it** for his own, and stand forth to himself the approved owner.

The treasure is not the main subject. 'Each' is the subject - a generic pronoun to mean individual people previously mentioned, or sometimes in general - and what follows is a list of things that apply to that one. When the treasure mentioned is referenced, the pronoun "it" is used. That is not the case with the final point, therefore it refers to the original subject.

Comment: Actually, here it would be: each (white) man. Think of the times...

Comment: Each of the six people mentioned in the first paragraph, surely?