# "stand forth to himself" - literal and figurative meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, [Chapter XXIII, passage 378/379](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_23), published 1892)

> That was indeed the chief singularity, the one thing conspicuous in their island life; the presence of that chest of bills and specie dominated the mind like a cathedral; and there were besides connected with it, certain irking problems well fitted to occupy the idle. Two thousand pounds were due to the Sydney firm: two thousand pounds were clear profit, and fell to be divided in varying proportions among six. It had been agreed how the partners were to range; every pound of capital subscribed, every pound that fell due in wages, was to count for one “lay.” Of these, Tommy could claim five hundred and ten, Carthew one hundred and seventy, Wicks one hundred and forty, and Hemstead and Amalu ten apiece: eight hundred and forty “lays” in all. What was the value of a lay? This was at first debated in the air and chiefly by the strength of Tommy's lungs. Then followed a series of incorrect calculations; . . . The figures were admittedly incorrect; the sum of the shares came not to £2000, but to £1996 6s.—£3 14s. being thus left unclaimed. But it was the nearest they had yet found, and the highest as well, so that the partners were made the less critical by the contemplation of their splendid dividends.
> . . .
> From talking and brooding on these figures, it was but a step to opening the chest; and once the chest open, the glamour of the cash was irresistible. Each felt that he must see his treasure separate with the eye of flesh, handle it in the hard coin, mark it for his own, and **stand forth to himself** the approved owner.

Neither do I know the literal meaning of "stand forth to himself" nor the figurative one. I understand every single word but they don't mean anything to me in context. What does "stand forth to himself" mean literally and figuratively in this context. Is there a synonym? Surely, this seems to be an obsolete phrase.

Comment: Look up "stand forth" as a phrase. All that remains then is to imagine an "as" after "himself."

Comment: No, it isn't that easy for a non-native speaker as you imagine. The phrase is "stand forth to himself" - that's a difficult combination for a non-native speaker, actually. And "stand forth" means something like "make a step forward" - that's a curious thing and my problem here. Maybe I'm a bit dull-witted but the thing isn't done with looking up "stand forth" and imagining "as" after "himself".

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this question was downvoted?

Comment: Related: [Issues with the wording "The treasure (?) must stand forth to himself the approved owner"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346504/issues-with-the-wording-the-treasure-must-stand-forth-to-himself-the-approv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means something like 'step forward', 'be seen to be [something]' - see [this](https://www.thesaurus.net/stand%20forth).

The men knew that a share of the money was due to them, but they longed to physically hold the cash, to really feel that they were the owner of their share.

Comment: Is "each of them wants to prove himself to be the approved owner" synonymous with "each felt that he must stand forth to himself the approved owner"?

Comment: @philphil I think you may be missing the work that "to" is doing. It's not about making themselves the approved owner to others, but about making themselves the approved owner in their own eyes.

Comment: My idea is "each one wants to prove himself to be the approved owner in his own eyes **and** in the eyes of the others".

Comment: @philphil I think you're interpreting "must" as "was under obligation to," but I think here it's more of "felt a powerful urge to." My paraphrase/amplification is "Each felt an irresistible urge to see his treasure, separate from the portions allotted to others, with his own eyes; and to handle it, to recognize it as his own, and to stand proudly in his own estimation as the rightful owner."

Comment: No, I take "must" to mean  - as you say - "each one felt being urged to . . .". "Must" is expressing an inner urge there - you are right.